# Storing in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel

In my `storage\app\public` folder, I have a folder called `book`

I save into it using the code below in my controller, which work

```
 $image = $request -> image -> store('books');
```

But I want to save a private file in a folder `storage\app\epub`, which I don't want to be accessible to the public

I used the code below in my controller, but it returns an error {Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found}

```
$epub =  Storage::disk('myDisk')->put('epub' . $file, $data);
```

Inside `Filesystems.php`

I added this

```
    'myDisk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/uploads'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'private',
    ],
```

My problem is I don't know how to save to another file except into  a public folder

Comment: You must add `Use Storage;` in your controller file for this error: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found"

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have imported storage facade in your controller 
like...

// import the storage facade top of your controller name declaration..
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

[image]